# Bootstrap2 tab navigation: tab content div position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, position

I misunderstand why DIV with ID="test1" overlap with left tab navigation but div with class="tab-content" doesn't.

[this is my example](http://jsfiddle.net/dveremeev/JCvZw/)

```
<div style="height: 160px;overflow: hidden;">
<div class="tabbable tabs-left" >

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"> 
            <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <div id="test1">
<div class="tab-content" >
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active"> Content tab1 </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The jsfiddle is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The tab-content has the css property `overflow: auto`. The tabs are `float: left`, and if the next elements are `overflow: auto` the div are automatically fixed to the width that is left by the element that is floating. It is usually used for spliting in two columns.

With this two examples should be clear:

With `overflow: auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/eugip9/tVLgj/

```
<div>
  <div class="a" style="width: 20%; float: left;">Whatever</div>
  <div class="b" style="overflow: auto">A very long text ... </div>   
</div>
```

Without `overflow: auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/eugip9/HVPhD/

```
<div>
  <div class="a" style="width: 20%; float: left;">Whatever</div>
  <div class="b">A very long text ... </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, changing overflow property for div test1 from default visible to auto,hidden or scroll solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for this answer in all the wrong places.